# What's the meaning of "professional society" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, interpretation

He is a member of numerous **professional societies.**

-From OALD

Is the boldedface type texts implies — *The groups people who come together because of their same profession.*

Comment: **Groups of  people who come together because they have the same profession**, yes.

Comment: Dunno about other countries, but in the UK it's *mandatory* to be a member of the relevant professional association in many cases (accountants, architects, engineers, nurses, solicitors,...). But I don't suppose many of those members often if ever "come together" to actually interact with their fellow members - it's not like they're social clubs.

Comment: Yours is the kind of question that’s easily resolved by a simple web search. Even Wikipedia has an article that would have settled it for. Here on ELL it is expected that one try to find answers on one’s own before posting questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Professional societies" just simply mean a society of professionals - a group of people who work on the same thing/profession. So in the sentence you presented it means he is part of many groups of people who all have different professions.